# How to connect Raspberry PI 3 Model B to BLE Motion Sensor

Tags: raspberry-pi, sensors, bluetooth-low-energy, infrared

I'm trying to connect my PIR motion sensor using gatttool and is giving me this error:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo gatttool -t random -b B8:7C6F:1A:D8:24 -I
 [B8:7C6F:1A:D8:24][LE]> connect
Attempting to connect to B8:7C6F:1A:D8:24
Error connect: Connection refused (111)
```

It's the same issue with this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32947807/cannot-connect-to-ble-device-on-raspberry-pi) but it didn't solved my issue.

I try other BLE device and it connects just fine except for this motion sensor. I tried to contact the motion sensor manufacturer but they didn't help me. The motion sensor is called IX34-BLE PIR Motion Sensor by Shenzhen Kaipule. Also the sensor works just fine with the manufacturer's alarm box and mobile app so I know that it does not have defects.